# NSIS User input page

Tags: input, nsis, blowfish

So I have a user input page using the code below and the text is being encrypted

How can I write this to a file

thae now can I read this from a file into a variable to decrypted it.

Then I want to display the decrypted message on screen in a Message box, but the \n\n needs to be converted to $\n before displaying so it displays correctly.

Example I enter in: (Note Control Enter gives you next line)

```
Hello World
It's a great day
```

When it decrypted is shows :

```
Hello World\n\nIt's a great day
```

ini File

```
[Settings]
NumFields=2
Title="Activation Code"
State=0

[Field 1]
Type=Text
Left=8
Right=-10
Top=12
Bottom=-15
flags=MULTILINE|VSCROLL

[Field 2]
Type=GroupBox
Left=0
Right=-1
Top=0
Bottom=-10
Text="Please enter in your Activation Code"
```

Code:

```
!include MUI.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

Page custom SetCustom ValidateCustom

Section Dummy
SectionEnd


Function SetCustom
   ReserveFile ".\test.ini"
  !insertmacro MUI_INSTALLOPTIONS_EXTRACT ".\test.ini"
  !insertmacro MUI_INSTALLOPTIONS_DISPLAY ".\test.ini"
 FunctionEnd

Function ValidateCustom
  !insertmacro MUI_INSTALLOPTIONS_READ $R1 ".\test.ini" "Field 1" "State"
  ${If} $R1 == ""
    Abort # Go back to page.
  ${Else}
    Var /GLOBAL textencryt

    blowfish::encrypt $R1 "1234password"
    StrCpy $textencryt $8   
    MessageBox MB_OK "Encrypted string is:$\n $textencryt"

    blowfish::decrypt $8 "1234password"
    StrCpy $textencryt $8   
    MessageBox MB_OK "Decrypted string is:$\n $textencryt"
  ${EndIf}

FunctionEnd
```

New code: (With issues)

```
!insertmacro MUI_INSTALLOPTIONS_READ $R1 "test.ini" "Field 1" "State"
  ${If} $R1 == ""
    Abort # Go back to page.
  ${Else}
    Var /GLOBAL textencryt

    blowfish::decrypt $R1 "1234password"
    StrCpy $textencryt $8
    MessageBox MB_OK "Decrypted string is:$\n $textencryt"

    !insertmacro MUI_INSTALLOPTIONS_READ $8 "test.ini" "Field 1" "HWND"
    System::Call 'USER32::SendMessage(i $8, i ${WM_GETTEXT}, i ${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN}, t.R1)'
    MessageBox MB_OK $R1
```

The original message was 
Example:
test user
code
12months
after being encrypted and I try and decrypt and looking at the results using 
"MessageBox MB_OK "Decrypted string is:$\n $textencryt" returns the decrypted message with the \n\n in there. (Example: test user\n\ncode\n\12months) it should come out like:
Example:
test user
code
12months

Comment: Don't use .\ relative paths.

Comment: what is the best method then?

Comment: Some of the macros already assumes the file is in $pluginsdir. For ReserveFile it is fine but "test.ini" is the same as ".\test.ini" in the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options.

You can use the INSTALLOPTIONS_READ_CONVERT helper function:

```
...

!insertmacro INSTALLOPTIONS_FUNCTION_READ_CONVERT

Function ValidateCustom
  !insertmacro INSTALLOPTIONS_READ_CONVERT $R1 "test.ini" "Field 1" "State"
  MessageBox MB_OK $R1
FunctionEnd
```

Or you can read the text directly from the control:

```
...

!include WinMessages.nsh

Function ValidateCustom
    !insertmacro MUI_INSTALLOPTIONS_READ $R1 "test.ini" "Field 1" "HWND"
    System::Call 'USER32::SendMessage(i $R1, i ${WM_GETTEXT}, i ${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN}, t.R1)'
    MessageBox MB_OK $R1
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: Second method you mentioned worked best for me. Now how do I take  a string and save it to a file, and then how do I take a file are read it to a string.

Example: string $8 I want to save to file ".\license.dat"

And then read the file ".\license.dat" and drop the info into a string.

I will always overwrite the file with new info if needed. and it will always only be one line of text.

Comment: 'FileOpen "c:\whatever\file.exe" w' and then FileWrite. Read the documentation for more details...

Comment: Wow, I really confused myself and now I am stuck. I have been playing around with the code and when i comes to converting the \n\n from the decrypt I noticed in your example it was trying to just read the Field 1, but I need it to convert it after I decrypt it.   I have added a new section to my OP with the new code.

Comment: Write the string to the .ini after decryption and read it back with INSTALLOPTIONS_READ_CONVERT